# How to get a moving Rectangle for my ping pong?

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

Here is my problem, I can not make my `Rectangle2D` variable `rect` move using mouse motion. What am I doing wrong? Maybe I did not understand right how does the `MouseListener` work.

```
public class CreppyRectangle extends JComponent {
private int viteza = 15;
private int yPosL = 100;
Rectangle2D rect;
Graphics2D g3d;
int lungimea = 40;
int latimea = 10;
int x = 0;
int y = 100;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new CreppyRectangle();
}

public CreppyRectangle() {
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }
     });
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            yPosL = e.getX();

            repaint(x, e.getX(), latimea, lungimea);
            System.out.println(e.getX());
        }
    });

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            final TestPane misha = new TestPane(Color.BLACK);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(misha);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;

    private int size = 10 ;
    private int xDelta = 5;
    private int yDelta = 5;

    public TestPane(Color foreground) {
        setForeground(foreground);

        Timer timer = new Timer(viteza , new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                xPos += xDelta;
                yPos += yDelta;
                if (xPos < 10) {
                    xPos = 10;
                    xDelta *= -1;
                    System.out.println(xDelta);
                } else if (xPos + size > getWidth()) {
                    xPos = getWidth() - size;
                    xDelta *= -1;
                } else if (yPos < 0) {
                    yPos = 0;
                    yDelta *= -1;
                    System.out.println(xDelta);
                } else if (yPos + size > getHeight()) {
                    yPos = getHeight() - size;
                    yDelta *= -1;
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.setCoalesce(true);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 200);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g3d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, yPosL, latimea, lungimea);
        g3d.draw(rect);
        g3d.fill(rect);
        g2d.setColor(getForeground());
        g2d.drawRect(xPos, yPos, size, size);
        g2d.fillRect(xPos, yPos, size, size);
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: As a side note - in the future you'll likely want some intermediary control.  This would allow things like easier swapping of control schemes (say, keyboard controls instead).  Failure to do so can result in locked controls, like all those windows games that would only work with xbox 360 controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you never actually add `CreppyRectangle` to anything, therefore, there's nothing capable of listening to mouse events.

Your setup is a little weird.  I don't know why you're bothering with extending from `JComponent`, when you should be putting all your logical into your `TestPane`

Also, I don't think you want to do `yPosL = e.getX()`, I think you want to try `yPosL = e.getY()` instead